Would sending the single keyword to Atlas Search on MongoDb perform better then sending a different word for each query?
Essentially send a keyword to search all queries, my current implementation builds compound queries based on the presence of various query parameters. Not sure which param method would perform the best given that the dataset will grow and the number of queries will grow too.
For example:
 let queryParams =`title=${keyword}&description=${keyword}&categorySearch=${keyword}&sortBy=${sortBy}&findCategory=${lookUpCategory}&seller=${seller}`;

or
let queryParams =`keyword=${keyword}`;

thus eliminating:
 if (
      req.query.soldBy ||
      req.query.seller ||
      req.query.description ||
      req.query.title ||
      req.query.categorySearch ||
      req.query.findCategory
    ) {
      const searchQuery: IProduct = {
        index: "default",
        compound: {
          must: [],
        },
      };

  if (req.query.seller) {
    searchQuery.compound.must.push({
      text: {
        query: req.query.seller,
        path: ["seller"],
        fuzzy: {
          maxEdits: 1,
        },
      },
    });
  }

  if (req.query.description) {
    searchQuery.compound.must.push({
      text: {
        query: req.query.description,
        path: ["description", "title", "categorySearch"],
        fuzzy: {
          maxEdits: 1,
        },
      },
    });
  }

etc... for
  if (req.query.keyword) {
    searchQuery.compound.must.push({
      text: {
        query: req.query.keyword,
        path: ["description", "title", "categorySearch", "all the rest"],
        fuzzy: {
          maxEdits: 1,
        },
      },
    });
  }


In general, simple is better.
However it depends what you are trying to do, both queries do different thing.
Your first query using must on different fields require the "keyword" to be in all fields. must is an AND.
Your second query will only require the "keyword" to be found in one of the fields (OR).
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/compound/

EDIT:
If you want to search different keywords in different fields at once, The most appropriate way is the first way, but in order to make it less cluttered you could use a for loop.
const LIST_OF_PARAMETERS = ["title","description"];

LIST_OF_PARAMETERS.forEach((param)=>{
 if (req.query[param]) must.push({"SEARCH OBJECT HERE"})
});

If the objective is to search a single keyword among a list of fields, then the second option is better.
